# How to make @HostListener work in IE 11?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I am building an angular application. I am using @HostListener which works fine in firefox, safari and chrome, but when I run it on Internet explorer 11, it does not work. Is there a way to make this work? Code looks like this.

```
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event']) onScrollEvent($event){
    console.log("hi");

}
```

The above prints hi to the console on scroll on safari, chrome and firefox, but does not work on IE11. How to make this work on IE11?

My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "inloggning",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.3.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0",
    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.1.7",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the required polyfills for IE? https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: Yes I went into the polyfills file and uncommented all of the parts for it but I get this

Comment: I have also tried with ('document:scroll', ['$event']) and that does not work either

Comment: What Angular version are you using?

Comment: angular version  ^4.0

Comment: I'd try 4.3.6 (the newest)

Comment: Ok thanks I got it to work.

Comment: How did you get it to work? By updating to a newer Angular version?

Comment: Hey sorry no, I am running IE11 in a virtual machine, and there was a problem with the caching in the virtual machine, so yeah not angular related.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function (event) {
    console.log("hi");
})
```